# Receive Error "Polymer::Attributes: couldn't decode Array as JSON" using iron-ajax in Polymer

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, polymer

I am trying to use *iron-ajax* to call an array and display the data on a simple page.  Every time I do so, I receive the following error in the console:

```
Polymer::Attributes: couldn't decode Array as JSON
```

I have searched everywhere but unfortunately have not found a solution.  I am utilizing two pages:

datasource-test.cfm - which returns the following JSON

```
[
{
LNAME: "Nanners",
GRADE: 10,
GENDER: "F",
ID: 88796848,
BIRTHDAY: "3/4/1999",
FNAME: "Nullie"
},
{
LNAME: "Nulled",
GRADE: 11,
GENDER: "M",
ID: 88485738,
BIRTHDAY: "4/25/1997",
FNAME: "Nullan"
},
{
LNAME: "Nullen",
GRADE: 9,
GENDER: "M",
ID: 88659685,
BIRTHDAY: "4/6/2000",
FNAME: "Nuller"
}
]
```

datasource-test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="elements/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="elements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="elements/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
<iron-ajax auto url="datasource-test.cfm" handle-as="json" last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
</template>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try and load datasource-test.html, that's when I receive my error. Is there any way I can successfully call and load elements for the response without Polymer throwing an error?

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the error because it's not valid JSON. Your keys need to be in double quotes:

```
{
"LNAME": "Nanners",
"GRADE": 10,
"GENDER": "F",
"ID": 88796848,
"BIRTHDAY": "3/4/1999",
"FNAME": "Nullie"
},...
```